# dynamic class inheritance using super

Tags: python-3.x, object, inheritance, superclass

I'm trying to dynamically create a class using `type()` and assign an `__init__` constructor which calls `super().__init__(...)`; however, when `super()` gets called I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Here is my code:

```
class Item():    
    def __init__(self, name, description, cost, **kwargs):
        self.name           = name
        self.description    = description
        self.cost           = cost
        self.kwargs         = kwargs

class ItemBase(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, cost):
        super().__init__(name, description, cost)

def __constructor__(self, n, d, c):
    super().__init__(name=n, description=d, cost=c)

item = type('Item1', (ItemBase,), {'__init__':__constructor__})
item_instance = item('MyName', 'MyDescription', 'MyCost')
```

Why is `super()` inside the `__constructor__` method not understanding the object parameter; and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution 1: Using `cls = type('ClassName', ...)`

Note the solution of sadmicrowave creates an infinite loop if the dynamically-created class gets inherited as `self.__class__` will correspond to the child class.

An alternative way which do not have this issue is to assigns `__init__` after creating the class, such as the class can be linked explicitly through closure. Example:

```py
# Base class
class A():
  def __init__(self):
    print('A')

# Dynamically created class
B = type('B', (A,), {})

def __init__(self):
  print('B')
  super(B, self).__init__()

B.__init__ = __init__

# Child class
class C(B):
  def __init__(self):
    print('C')
    super().__init__()


C()  # print C, B, A
```

### Solution 2: Using `MyClass.__name__ = 'ClassName'`

An alternative way to dynamically create class is to define a class inside the function, then reassign the `__name__` and `__qualname__` attributes:

```
class A:
  
  def __init__(self):
    print(A.__name__)


def make_class(name, base):

  class Child(base):
    def __init__(self):
      print(Child.__name__)
      super().__init__()

  Child.__name__ = name
  Child.__qualname__ = name
  return Child


B = make_class('B', A)


class C(B):
  
  def __init__(self):
    print(C.__name__)
    super().__init__()

C()  # Display C B A
```

Comment: Great follow up - I’m changing the accepted answer as I’m always open to better solutions :)

Comment: This article provides a good explanation of how `super(B, self)` works, under 'A super() Deep Dive': https://realpython.com/python-super/

Comment: Is there any way to put B into a class or initiate it from a class call?

Comment: @misantroop I'm not sure what you mean. An alternative way it to declare inside your `make_class('MyClass')` function:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
```
Then set `B.__name__ = 'MyClass'` and `B.__qualname__ = 'MyClass'`, and `return B`

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I solved the issue.  I reference the `type()` method to dynamically instantiate a class with variable references as such:

```
def __constructor__(self, n, d, c, h):
    # initialize super of class type
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name=n, description=d, cost=c, hp=h)

# create the object class dynamically, utilizing __constructor__ for __init__ method
item = type(item_name, (eval("{}.{}".format(name,row[1].value)),), {'__init__':__constructor__})
# add new object to the global _objects object to be used throughout the world
self._objects[ item_name ] = item(row[0].value, row[2].value, row[3].value, row[4].value)
```

There may be a better way to accomplish this, but I needed a fix and this is what I came up with... use it if you can.

Comment: The infinite loop problem mentioned below makes this a non-viable solution.